# How to get authenticated before calling a servlet using java client(code)

Tags: java, servlets, cas

I am trying to call a servlet using java, but before that i need to get authenticated to call that servlet. when I call the URL as per the below example first it is getting redirected to login page, Is there anyway to pass the user name and password through java. Can anybody suggest how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no **bellow example**.

Comment: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/authentication.html

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares - but your comment is a "bellow" comment.  :-) :-)  [Hint: lookup "bellow" in a dictionary.]

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway to pass the user name and password through java.

There is no general answer to this.  Theoretically it is possible, but in practice it depends on how the site implements login.

You need to look at what happens when you login on *that specific site* using a web browser ... and reproduce the browser-side behavior in your client code.  This is *typically* just a matter of sending some parameter in GET request arguments or POST data, but it *could* be more complicated.